# How to use JS variable in "path" attribute while creating a dynamic elements in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am using spring framework and Ajax. I am getting a list in JSON response and based on that i am creating a dynamic element with my Java script function. i am using the index of for loop inside the "path" attr but it is not working. below is code snippet

```
for(var i=0;i<response.locStrategy.lstReplacement.length;i++) {
   newContent = 
                '<tr><td class ="RMSLabel"><strong class="required">*</strong>         
                     spring:message code="strategy"/></td>'+
                '<td class="RMSInput" width="20%">        
                 <form:select path="employee.locStrategy.lstReplacement['+i+'].strategy"  
                              id="strategy'+i+'">'+
                '<form:options items="${rmsForm.employee.locStrategy.lstStrategy}"     
                          itemValue="value" itemLabel="label"/>'+
                '</form:select>'+
                '</td>'+
```

i am trying to bind the fields uniquely by appending the index of for loop. when i run this i am getting below exception

SEVERE: Invalid property 'employee.locStrategy.lstReplacement[+i+]' of bean class [com.citigroup.rms.population.beans.RMSEmployee]: Invalid index in property path 'lstReplacement[+i+]';nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "+i+";

Please suggest.
Thanks

Comment: why don't you print this to the console so you can see what string is being created

Comment: actually from exception it seems that is not treating i as a variable.

Comment: I know, but to help hunt down the cause, do a `console.log` with that whole string (not `newContent`, but the code that you're setting `newContent` equal to, wrap in a console.log call)

Comment: I am actually trying to set newContent into a div like below    $('<div id = "div_replacement">').html(newContent).replaceAll('#div_replacement');

Comment: If you're unwilling to even try what I asked then unfortunately I cannot help.

Comment: I am trying but even before going to the code console.log() it is throwing exception. The above code is inside the ajax response but i am getting exception when initially page loads. Ajax call has not even made yet.

Comment: You need to comment out that code and put the console.log call in, and wrap it in a try...catch and in the catch, log the error

Comment: were you able to print out to the console?